# Union of infinitely many disjoint intervals

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I am trying to think of a way to define a sequence $\{C_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of mutually disjoint intervals of real numbers, such that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n = (-\infty, \infty)$. Here's what I've come up with so far:

Let $C_1 = (-\infty, 1]$,

and for $n = 2, 3, \cdots$,

$C_n = (n-1, n].$

So I claim that  $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n = (-\infty, \infty)$. Is there any error with my work? Thank you.

Comment: No, it's correct.

Comment: If you want to show that the union is $\mathbb{R}$, then the usual trick would be to fix an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then show that $x$ is contained in $A_n$ for some $n$.  The value of $\lceil x \rceil$ may be relevant.  It might also be helpful if you used consistent notation:  do you want to call your intervals $A_n$ or $C_n$?

Comment: I think I am confused about how to write a rigorous proof. If I said something like, Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, $x \in (-\infty, 1]$ or $x \in (1, \infty)$. If $x \in (-\infty, 1] = C_1$ then $x \in \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n$. If $x \in (1, \infty)$, then for some $n \in \{2, 3, \cdots\}$, we will have $x \in (n-1, n]$, and hence the result. I have a hunch that this isn't exactly correct/complete, but would you say it is on the right track?

Comment: Let $n$ be the ceiling of $x$. Then $x\in (n-1, n]$.